# Is a value inside an NSDictionary released when removed?

Tags: objective-c

I have something along the line of this :

```
@implementation ImageLoader
NSMutableDictionary *_tasks;

- (void) loadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url callback:(SMLoaderCallback)callback {
    NSMutableArray *taskList = [_tasks objectForKey:urlString];
    if (taskList == nil) {
        taskList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
        [taskList addObject:callback];
        [_tasks setObject:taskList forKey:urlString];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                for (SMLoaderCallback cb in taskList) {
                    cb(image, nil);
                }
                [_tasks removeObjectForKey:url.absoluteString];
            });
        });
    } else {
        [taskList addObject:callback];
    }
}
@end
```

In here, I'm trying to queue up image downloads to gain performance (as an exercise only). So I'm keeping a NSDictionary that maps an URL with an array of callbacks to be called whenever the data is downloaded.

Once the image is downloaded, I no longer need this array, so I remove it from the dictionary.

I would like to know if, in this code (with ARC enabled), my array along with the callbacks are correctly released when I call `[_tasks removeObjectForKey:url.absoluteString]`.

Comment: Yes, `removeObjectForKey:` releases the removed object. It would be a terrible implementation if it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project uses *ARC* and that dictionary is the only thing that is referencing to those values, **yes**. it will be remove permanently.

**ARC** keeps track of number of objects that is pointing to some other object and it will remove it as soon as the count reaches 0.

so adding to dictionary -> reference count += 1

removing from dictionary -> reference count -= 1

Somewhe

Comment: *"ARC keeps track of number of objects that is pointing to some other object and it will remove it as soon as the count reaches 0."* - that is misleading. That has nothing to do with ARC. ARC means that calls to `retain` and `release` are automatically added to the code. That's all ARC does. An object is deallocated once its retain count reaches 0 whether you use ARC or not.